# How do I gather OS information about all users in AD?

Tags: scripting, directory

I'm looking to make a script or something along those lines which will allow me to check the OS version of all users within the AD, without interrupting daily operations.
So far i've found this script which finds OS information, http://www.windowsadminscripts.com/coding/networking/osinfo/.

But, I have no idea on how to apply this script to all users in the AD.
Any advice?

Comment: Unless your company is staffed with robots, users won't have an operating system, only their computers do....

Comment: ouch you got me...

Comment: @HBruijn In Active Directory [computers *are* users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680987(v=vs.85).aspx). Check the `subclass of`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this goal by using a [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx) command.
Open up a PowerShell cmd window and enter the following command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion -Wrap –Auto
```

This command is filtering all computers for all their properties. It then redirects the output into a formatted table.

The only attributes that the table contains are the computer name, operating system description, service pack, and OS version. It also automatically sizes and wraps the data.

In order to find all servers in the domain, run the following command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack -Wrap -Auto
```

In order to find all servers running Windows Server 2008, run:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*2008*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack -Wrap -Auto
```

In order to find all servers running Windows Server 2008 R2, run:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*r2*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack -Wrap -Auto
```

I hope this answers your question.

Edit:

In order to run the `Get-ADComputer` command, you will have to install "Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows".

Follow [This guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7.aspx) in order to do so.
Then, while in a PowerShell Terminal, type:

```
import-module activedirectory
```

And then re-run the `Get-ADComputer` command.

Check the following screenshot, you see an error there because the first time I ran the command I didn't have the Active Directory module for PowerShell installed:
[image]

Comment: Hey there, That seems to answer my question however, I can't get the command working this is the error I get: The term 'Get-ADComputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

Comment: Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: Windows Server 2003

Comment: Please review my edited answer.

Comment: You'll need the Microsoft Active Directory PowerShell modules... and possibly [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852) if your DCs are only 2003/2008.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it working today, thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to the Computers your users use, then this information is already stored in AD for any Domain Joined PC.  You should be able to script pulling these attributes from the Computer Objects:  `operatingSystem`, `operatingSystemServicePack`, & `operatingSystemVersion`.

Comment: Could you give me a more detailed explanation i'm not that literate in this field.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the powershell commands posted above, you can also use a gui based tool called [PowerGUI](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/). This is pretty handy tool to have which makes ActiveDirectory management a lot easier. You can accomplish what you are asking in this question and much more. While you are using the gui, it actually runs powershell commands in the background. You can view the scripts that it runs.

I would also recommend checking out Quest [Active Roles](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) which provide a wealth of powershell cmdlets.